# Assert.IsType<> not working properly with Moq framework

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

I getting the following error when try check type of mock Object:

```
 Assert.IsType() Failure
 Expected: ProjetoAxion.Domain.Entities.User
 Actual:   Castle.Proxies.UserProxy
```

Example:

```
var userMock = Mock<User>().Object;
Assert.IsType<User>(userMock);
```

How can I Assert it type with Moq is type mocked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way how `moq` internally works. It uses `DynamicProxy` under the hood to create an interceptable proxy where the proxy `Castle.Proxies.UserProxy` extends `User`. Otherwise, how would `moq` be able to intercept invocations... Knowing that fact you could use `IsAssignableFrom<User>` instead of `IsType<User>`.

```
Assert.IsAssignableFrom<User>(userMock);
```